# Segmentation fault in linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I can't seem to get rid of segmentation fault in 2 places.
This is the whole code. I would be so grateful if someone could let me know why it isn't working and how can I make it work

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Key, typename Info>
class Sequence
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Key key;
        Info info;
        Node *next;
    };
    Node *head;

public:
    Sequence<Key, Info>() { head = NULL; };
    ~Sequence<Key, Info>(){};
    void print();
    void pushBack(Key key, Info info);
};

template <typename Key, typename Info>
void Sequence<Key, Info>::pushBack(Key key, Info info)
{
    Node *ptr;
    ptr = new Node;
    ptr->key = key;
    ptr->info = info;
    if (head)
    {
        Node *temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) // here there is segmentation fault
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        head = ptr;
    }
}
template <typename Key, typename Info>

void Sequence<Key, Info>::print()
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        Node *ptr = head;
        while (ptr->next != NULL) // segmentation fault  happens here too
        {
            std::cout << ptr->info << std::endl;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Empty sequence" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Sequence<int, int> seq;
    seq.pushBack(1, 5);
    seq.pushBack(2, 6);
    seq.print();
}
```

I tried many solutions proposed online but none of them seemed to work for me. I would be grateful if you could look at it

Comment: You never initialize `Node::next` to be a null pointer anywhere. That means it will have an *indeterminate* value, and dereferencing it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: sometimes i think we need an SE site called linked lists. it would have only a couple of answers though (one of which would be "simply don't" - everything else would be a dupe.

Comment: If you are using a modern version of c++ you can replace `Node *next;` in `struct Node { ...} ` with `Node *next = nullptr;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set `next`

```
Node *ptr;
ptr = new Node;
ptr->key = key;
ptr->info = info;
ptr->next = NULL; // <--- here
```

Honestly it would be better if you looked at your own code rather than looking online. Especially you should learn how to use a debugger. If you were experienced at using a debugger you would have found this error in minutes.